# Adding a delay on mouseout with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm writing a function to fire a fadein - fadeout effect on mouseover / mouseout, all works right, but now I need to add a delay on mouseout.
When the mouse hovering a link the div related has to fadein and the other ones need to fadeout.

I try many times without any success...

Here's the code:

```
function selectedSwitch() {
            $('.selectedSwitch').each(function() {
                $(this).on("mouseover", function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var current = $(this).data('selected');
                    $('.selected.post-'+current).stop().animate({'opacity': 1}, 200);
                    $('.selected.post-'+current).siblings().stop().animate({'opacity': 0}, 200);
                });
                $(this).on("mouseout", function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var current = $(this).data('selected');
                    $('.selected.post-'+current).stop().animate({'opacity': 0}, 200);
                });
            });
    }
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: I don't really understand the question.  Are you trying to wait until the first animation is complete and then do the mouseout animation?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delay the triggering of the event but you can add delay in the code that executes by using `setTimeout` function

Comment: how did u try ? setTimeout is a function not a property.. eg. setTimeout(functionName, TimeoutInMilliseconds); add this in your event and functionName will be called after TimeoutInMilliseconds expires.